# Sorting arrays from lowest to highest numbers with ratios using methods in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am writing a program that takes in the number of ingredients. The prog

This is my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Restaurant {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int count = scan.nextInt();

    
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: *" ... but my results are obviously incorrect."* - Include an example of the inputs and corresponding incorrect results in the question.

Comment: Why do you expect highest calories is for rice when 3rd parameter is 37 which is the lowest ?

Comment: Is it okay, if we can create new POJOs and do it with Java streams (i.e., Java-8 and above) ?

Comment: What do you mean POJOs?

Comment: POJOs = Plain old java object. Basically, a new class to holds information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this sortCalories function to the one below. Also you need to pass price array as second parameter like this `sortCalories(calories,price, ingredientName);`:

```
public static void sortCalories(double[] calories,double[] price, String[] ingredientName) { 
        double temp;
        String temp1;

        for (int p=0; p<calories.length; p++) {
            for (int j=p+1; j<calories.length; j++) {
                if(calories[p]/price[p]>calories[j]/price[j]) {
                    temp = calories[p];
                    calories[p] = calories[j];
                    calories[j] = temp;
                    
                    temp = price[p];
                    price[p] = price[j];
                    price[j] = temp;
                    
                    temp1 = ingredientName[p];
                    ingredientName[p] = ingredientName[j];
                    ingredientName[j] = temp1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh wow, I only had to change like 3 lines of code. Thanks so much!